# How do you decode a continuous bit stream in node?

Tags: node.js, tcp, buffer, bitstream

I am trying to implement [this protocol](https://wiki.teltonika.lt/index.php?title=RUT955_Protocols) using TCP. Most of it is received as a Buffer and can be read fine using .toString('hex') but there is the AVL part that mentions "Encoded using continuous bit stream. Last byte padded to align to byte boundary" where the data seems to be encoded in a different way that I cannot read properly. How am I supposed to read the continuous bit steam part?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you wrote `I cannot read properly` consider adding some code. The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: The TCP data arriving in variable data are read as: data.toString(‘hex’). The beginning and start of the Buffer are correct (as described in the link) but the AVL part is “encoded using continuous bit stream” so toString(‘hex’) doesn’t return the expected values. The question is how does a continuous but steam differ from a Buffer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the integer value of number of record you have read in 4 bytes buffer encoded using continuous bit stream:

```
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(4);
buffer.writeIntBE([INT_VALUE], 0, 4);
```